# Checkstyle configuration for annotations

Tags: java, maven, annotations, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Can't resolve how should I configure checkstyle file for maven plugin. I have snippets like these:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Session.GET_ENTRIES_BY_STATUS, query = "some SQL query"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Session.CHECK_SESSION, query = "some SQL query"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Session.DELETE_ENTRIES_BY_LASTDATE, query = "some SQL query")
})
```

Or another annotation init:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "username",
    "icon_emoji",
    "channel",
    "attachments"
})
```

And the output in result.xml always shows it as a violation:

```
<error line="30" severity="warning" message="&apos;}&apos; have incorrect indentation level 0, expected level should be 8." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.indentation.IndentationCheck"/>
```

My indentation block is:

```
<module name="Indentation">
    <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
    <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
    <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
    <property name="throwsIndent" value="8"/>
    <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
    <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
</module>
```

And right curly blocks are:

```
<module name="RightCurly">
    <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_DO"/>
</module>
<module name="RightCurly">
    <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
    <property name="option" value="alone"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT"/>
</module>
```

How can I get rid of this violation if such a listing seems to be code style correct?